# Select distinct value ignoring extra characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with phone numbers

```
example:

4685293

+924685293

1254152
```

I need to select first two values as one ignoring the +92

Can I do that in a query or do I have to do it manually through my code.

Answer (score 2):

To select your local phone number just use [RIGHT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(phone,7) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: the length may vary so I cannot write the 7 here :)

Comment: and +92 can also vary. can I compare the column's value somehow to check if it contains the previous value?

Comment: @SyedRizwanAli It's not clear what do you mean by the 'PREVIOUS VALUE'.

Comment: I mean can I pick the first row value and compare with second row and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the patterns you want to ignore with:

```
REPLACE(example,'+92','')
```

If there can different patterns but there is always 3 characters (+xx) then you might be able to do the following:

```
CASE WHEN phone LIKE '+[0-9][0-9]%' THEN 
RIGHT(phone,LEN(phone)-3)
ELSE
phone
END
```

Comment: SO is not for quick answers - please, provide valid code with explanations for generic case, if any

Comment: Added a different answer to comply to the comments made in other answers

Answer (score 0):

you could try selecting only the last 7 characters...

```
select distinct(substring(phoneno,-7)) from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`try this`

```
 ;with cte as(
     select replace(ph,'+92','') as replaced,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ph) as rn
      from [dbo].[ph] 
     )

     select * from cte where rn <3
```